# What is the meaning of "There ain't a durn thing"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Big George talking to William Blake about hair.

> Your hair is soft. It's like a girl's. By God, it is soft. Now how do
>   you get it that way? See, this old stuff of mine, it just Well, it's 
>   just like old barn hay. **There ain't a durn thing** you can do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slang for "There isn't a damned thing you can do with it", meaning that there is nothing that you can do with Big George's hair.